# Freezing a graph using the C API

Tags: tensorflow

I have recently started using the TensorFlow C API and have created an object that can load a model created in Python and run it.

Is it possible to freeze a graph and save the frozen version using the C API after loading the graph's definition file and restoring its variables created in Python ?

A code snippet of the "freezing" step would be greatly appreciated, though, general pointers on how to achieve this would be a great help, too.

Thanks!

P.S. I couldn't find a single post about this online.

EDIT:

I have posted this question at the TensorFlow's original github forums and have gotten a rather interesting response.

The response was: "There's no way to freeze it using only the C API. Also freezing is unsupported going forward. @gargn to confirm."

This is a link to the discussion https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32965

Comment: Can you provide some of the code you have written for more context? It is hard to help otherwise

Comment: Hey, razdi. Thanks for the comment :) What I have done so far is just more or less a standard way of creating a graph, creating a session, loading a graph and restoring variables using the C API. What do you think I should post that would make it easier to get help in this case ? All I need is just general pointers, the functions that can be used to achieve this or pseudo code. I don't really need a precise implementation. P.S. I have Googled how this could be done but couldn't find a single post about it.